# Navigation to other page works in render() call but not in separate function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) third party component, here is my code:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// ==============
// Profile Screen
// ==============
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Profile Page</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('Detail')}>Next</TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }

  onEditProfile(event) {
    () => navigate('Detail');
  }
}

// ==============
// Detail Screen
// ==============
class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Detail',
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Detail Page</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

// ==============
// Routing
// ==============
const ModelStack = StackNavigator({
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ModelStack', () => ModelStack);
export default ModelStack;
```

In the `<TouchableHighlight>`'s onPress event, it works; when I put the exact content in `onEditProfile()` just as shown above, it does not work. Why? How can I put the action in a function?

Extra question:

1. <s>How can I change the "Back" wording when it is navigated (pushed) to next page?</s> **UPDATE**: I found it, it can be set via `headerBackTitle` in `navigationOptions`
2. Can I move the `ProfileScreen` & `DetailScreen` class to separate JS file?

---

**UPDATE**: Updated Code `onPressEditProfile` :

```
onPressEditProfile(event) {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log('Clicked Edit Profile');
    () => navigate('Detail');
}
```

The above code raised the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

The line of error is on the first line of the `onPressEditProfile` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line inside the function

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

Yes you can do it. You can a declare navigation const for all the screens in a separate file and export that const. Then make different files for different screens and navigate to those screens .

Updated code

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
// ==============
// Profile Screen
// ==============
class ProfileScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Profile Page</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onEditProfile()}><Text>Next</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }

  onEditProfile() {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     navigate('Detail');
  }
}

// ==============
// Detail Screen
// ==============
class DetailScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Detail',
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Detail Page</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

// ==============
// Routing
// ==============
const ModelStack = StackNavigator({
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen },
});


export default ModelStack;
```

Comment: I received the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`